# IE9 jQuery Ajax Not Working

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, internet-explorer-9

I am using jQuery 1.6.1 and IE9. I am running the page on my machine trying to request data from a server. My Javascript looks like this:

```
var baseURL = "http://1.1.1.1/cgi-bin/ipcxml.cgi?";
var path = "scm:scm/data/system_names";
var fullURL = baseURL + path;
$.ajax (
    {
        url: fullURL,
        cache: true,
        context: $("#" + element),
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "xml",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
        alert (data);
        }
    }
);
```

When I run this code and I watch for the network traffic in the IE developer tools, I don't see the request go out. Does anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try in another browser? Does it work?

Comment: In Firefox 4, the request sends, but no response comes back. If I do the straight XMLHttpRequest object (handling for IE6 and IE5), everything works in IE, but not in Firefox. I want to get jQuery working for cross-browser support.

Comment: The empty response make me think that the issue is probably with `crossDomain: true`. You need something to handle it, because most browser block XSS by default. IE is being less restrictive, like always. See [Same_origin_policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). **edit**: I noticed I didn't answer your original question : No idea why you are not seeing the request. Maybe you should try to do it localy first.

Comment: Hit F12. Go to the Script tab. Click Start Debugging. Reload your page.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's also how I know what the network traffic is doing. If that had given me an answer, I wouldn't be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the root cause of your problem, but colon (`:`) and slash (`/`) characters have to be [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) when used in query strings. Try:

```
var fullURL = baseURL + encodeURIComponent(path);
```

Comment: A great point that I never considered; however, it did not fix my problem.

Comment: @Nik, apart from the same origin policy issues already mentioned in your question's comments, the only potential problem I can see would be related to the `context` setting. Are you sure `$("#" + element)` actually matches anything?

Answer (score 4):

I was having problems with my tab, the content inside it was not updating like it did with other browsers. I scanned through the net and finally i found my solution:

```
cache:false
```

IE security causes the cache related problem so turning the cache to false solved my prob. Hope it helps